# approach to limit/continuity problem with multiple variables

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

> Let $g: \Bbb{R^2} \backslash \{(0,0)\} \to \Bbb{R}$
> with
> $$g(x,y)=\dfrac {\cos x - \cos y}{5(x^2+y^2)}$$
> Determine $G(x)=\lim\limits_{y \to 0}g(x,y) \;\; x \in \Bbb{R} $

This is the problem and my work so far. I am unsure if the Taylor approach is needed or if I can use use LL'Hôpital's rule to make the problem more simple.
[image]

Comment: you can use the identity of $cos(x)=2cos^2\frac{x}{2}-1$ instead of the Taylor expansion. Also, it would be better if you can type the above on mathSE instead of posting a picture. This practice is important so that other users can be helped as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct for $G(x)$ and you can also apply L'Hôpital's rule twice to obtain $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos(x)-1}{5x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{-\sin(x)}{10x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{-\cos(x)}{10}=-\frac{1}{10}.$$

Since $G(x)$ has a removable discontinuity at $x=0$, if we define $$G(x)=\begin{cases}-\frac{1}{10}\space\space\space\text{for $x=0$}\\\frac{\cos(x)-1}{5x^2}\space\space\space\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

then $G(x)$ becomes continuous.

---

Note that $$\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}g(0,y)=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos(y)}{5y^2}$$
$$=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(y)}{10y}=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos(y)}{10}=\frac{1}{10}$$

so it follows that the $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}g(x,y)$ does not exist.

---

Your numerator for $g(0,y)$ should be $$g(0,y)=\frac{\frac{y^2}{2!}-y^2t(y)}{5y^2}$$

Comment: Yes okay I see now. I made a mistake. We can conclude that G(x) is continous with the piecewise function and that we can not find a c=g(0,0) since they obtain different values from different sides at the pont, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I am abit confused about the removeable discontinuity. I would have thought the function is not continous because it isnt defined at that value?

Comment: $G(x)$ is not continuous at $x=0$ since it is undefined there, but if we define $G(x)$ as the piecewise function above (i.e set its value at $x=0$ to be $-\frac{1}{10}$), then $G(x)$ **becomes** continuous.